# Link C++ libraries with ToolChain.cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, toolchain

I have the following situation:

I'm trying to integrate some C++ libraries to an already existing software (also written in C++). The README file provides some guide on how to develop as a Client and gives the following **ToolChain.cmake** file as an example:

```
# Example ToolChain.cmake
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang-8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++-8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

On the other hand, I had the following **CMakeLists.txt** file, which successfully compiled linked the libraries that I wanted.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(osi_messages_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/TCP_Client.cpp)

# Load the Protobuf module and fail if not found
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

# Add 
add_subdirectory(open-simulation-interface)


get_directory_property(OSI_VERSION_MAJOR DIRECTORY open-simulation-interface DEFINITION VERSION_MAJOR)

set(OSIVERSION "${OSI_VERSION_MAJOR}.${OSI_VERSION_MINOR}.${OSI_VERSION_PATCH}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} open_simulation_interface)
```

My question is, how do I integrate this **CMakeLists.txt** file into the **ToolChain.cmake** file? If I try to paste this to the **ToolChain.cmake** file I get the following error messages:

```
CMake Error at HAD/HADClient/ToolChain.cmake:1 (project):
  Language 'C' is currently being enabled.  Recursive call not allowed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  HAD/HADClient/build/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

**Edit:**

This is how I call `cmake` (as specified in the README of the software).

```
cmake \
    -G "Ninja" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Client \
    -DLIBCARLA_BUILD_RELEASE=ON \
    -DLIBCARLA_BUILD_DEBUG=OFF \
    -DLIBCARLA_BUILD_TEST=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/ToolChain.cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install-folder \
    /path/to/carla-root-folder
```

Now it does what is supposed to, I think I was sending the build files to another directory, which wasn't the build.

Comment: What library do you want to link in the toolchain? `Protobuf`? Or `open_simulation_interface`? Note, that toolchain is normally sets only **compiler-specific** settings, not a **project-specific** ones. Linking with `Protobuf` is *project-specific*, so it could be done in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I want to link ```open_simulation_interface```, which uses ```Protobuf```. If I understand you correctly, I could and should use both files separately, right? The problem is that when I call cmake it doesn't seem to take the ```CMakeLists``` file into account.

Comment: "The problem is that when I call cmake it doesn't seem to take the CMakeLists file into account." - This shouldn't occure. How do you call `cmake`? Please, update the **question post** with that information.

Comment: C++ standard and preprocessor defines imho should not be part of the toolchain file. Furthermore you shouldn't try to "integrate" `CMakeLists.txt` files in a toolchain file or the other way around. the cmake tool is responsible for combining both. One thing that may have gone wrong in your scenario though may be the fact that you didn't specify the toolchain file on the initial configuration; you may need to remove the `CMakeCache.txt` file before running cmake again...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I indeed was trying to integrate one into  the other; thanks for the clarification. In all the calls that I executed, I may have given the wrong path to the `ToolChain.cmake` file.